# Find string which reaches maximum

Tags: r, string, max

Let's consider very simply function :

```
find_max <- function(num) {
  vec <- c()
  t <- seq(-1,1,num)
    for (i in 1:length(t)) {
      for (j in 1:length(t)) {
        vec <- append(vec, setNames(((i-j)/2),paste('i'=t[i],'j'=t[j])))
      }
    }
  names(which.max(vec))
} 
> find_max(0.1)
[1] "0.9 0.1"
```

That returns strings for which maximum is taken.

Also let's consider another function `mean_bound` which takes vector containing two strings and if mean of those is less than 0.3 it returns 1 and 0 otherwise.

```
mean_bound <- function(strings) {
  check_vec <- c()
  convert_string <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit((gsub(".*(\\d\\.\\d).*(\\d\\.\\d)", "\\1 \\2", strings)), " ")))
  ifelse(mean(convert_string) < 0.3, check_vec <- 1, check_vec <- 0)
}
mean_bound(find_max(0.1)) 
0
```

Now I want to create function `find_mean_bound_max` which will do exactly what `find_max` is doing but with mean_bound condition added (so to find two best strings). So loosly speaking I want to find strings for which we have :

[image]

Do you know how it can be performed ? I tried to put this mean_bound somewhere in find_max but without any results.

**Edit**

*find_max*

`find_max(num)` - function which calculates difference (i-j)/2 where
i,j are numbers created by `seq(-1,1,num)` (this function is meaningless but it's created only for purpose of example). It returns i,j (as strings) for which difference (i-j)/2 takes maximum.

So in example I provided before we have :

```
find_max(0.1)
[1] "0.9 0.1"
```

because difference 0.9-0.1 = 0.8 is the biggest in for i,j in set `seq(-1,1,0.1)`.`

*mean_bound*

mean_bound is a function which takes two strings and convert them into numbers. After that it calculates mean of those and if it's less than 0.3 it returns 1 and 0 otherwise. In our example :

```
  mean_bound(find_max(0.1))
```

it's equivalent form of `mean_bound("0.9 0.1")`. It returns 0, because `mean(c(0.9,0.1))=0.5>0.3`

So what I'm looking for is to find maximum using function `find_max`, but with condition that `mean_bound` gives 1.

So the output of `find_mean_bound_max(num = 0.1)` should be '0.4 0.1' because

(1) difference equals to `0.4 - 0.1 = 0.3`

(2) mean is  `(0.4 + 0.1)/2 = 0.25 < 0.3`

Hope now it's more clean to you!

Comment: It is not clear to me what your `find_max` or `mean_bound` function is doing. Are you open to solutions which doesn't use the functions which you have written? If yes, can you provide 4-5 example inputs along with their corresponding output?

Comment: Hey @RonakShah thank you very much for your comment. I would highly prefer soulution using find_max and mean_bound. I updated my question to be more clear. If you have any questions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Use simply :

```
find_max <- function(num) {
  vec <- c()
  t <- seq(0.1,0.9,num)
    for (i in 1:length(t)) {
      for (j in 1:length(t)) {
        if (mean(c(t[i],t[j]))<0.3){
        vec <- append(vec, setNames(((i-j)/2),paste('i'=t[i],'j'=t[j])))}
      }
    }
  names(which.max(vec))
}

find_max(0.1) 
"0.4 0.1"
```